# how to use new apple id?

Tags: apple-id

I have created the Apple ID. Now when I try to download anything from the App Store and I log in with my ID and password, I see the message "this ID has not been yet used". What should I do? I have no more knowledge about these procedures.

Comment: Do you mean that you used a new Apple ID to login with your Mac?

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to use a new Apple ID with your MacBook Pro you will have to do the following:

> - Pull down the  Apple menu and go to “System Preferences”
>     Choose “iCloud”
> - Click the “Sign Out” button to log out of the existing Apple ID on that user account – note the message that logging out of that Apple ID may impact iCloud Drive documents and data, if you don’t want to do that, don’t log out, and instead use a different user account in OS X

When iCloud finishes logging out of the Apple ID, the iCloud preference panel changes to a simple login screen
Log into the other Apple ID you wish to change to on the active Mac user account
Log in to a new Apple ID on Mac OS X>